# Setting the initial balance of an account in ganache-cli

Tags: testrpc

How can I set the initial balance of an account when launching `ganache-cli` (aka `testrpc`)?

There's nothing in `ganache-cli --help` to indicate that this is possible.

However, when I launch `ganache-cli --acctKeys=accounts.txt`, I can clearly see that each account has a balance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

OK, found it in the [Ganache Command Line](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#command-line) guide:

`-e` or `--defaultBalanceEther`: Amount of ether to assign each test account. Default is 100.

Apparently, `ganache-cli --help` doesn't quite tell you everything that you need to know...

UPDATE:

The value set via the `--defaultBalanceEther` parameter doesn't seem to have any impact on the amount of ether assigned to each test account (as suggested in the docs). I was, however, able to achieve my purpose by explicitly "declaring" an account with a large enough balance. For example:

```
ganache-cli --account="0x0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef,1000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

The first part of the `account` parameter value is the private key of the account, which must be given as a 64-character hexadecimal string (i.e., `0x` followed by 64 hexadecimal-base characters).

The second part of the `account` parameter value is the balance, which can be provided in either decimal or hexadecimal format.

Comment: As of Ganache CLI v6.1.3 (ganache-core: 2.1.2), I found that `ganache --defaultBalanceEther 10000` was not working but `ganache -e 10000` did work.