# i'm creating new account and when i get the balance for that account it returns 0 and cant do any transaction saying dont have enough funds

Tags: web3js, ganache, nethereum, c#

How to load funds/ether into newly created account. I'm using Ganache and Web3js

```
            var web3 = new Web3("HTTP://localhost:7545");
            var privateAccount = await web3.Personal.NewAccount.SendRequestAsync("ethics subject regret beyond coach grant soft clean sauce identify benefit club");
            var accountsList = await web3.Eth.Accounts.SendRequestAsync();
            var result = await web3.Personal.UnlockAccount.SendRequestAsync(privateAccount, "ethics subject regret beyond coach grant soft clean sauce identify benefit club", 1500000);
            var gas = await web3.Eth.DeployContract.EstimateGasAsync(ABI, byteCode, privateAccount);

            var balance = await web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync(privateAccount);
            var transaction = await web3.Eth.DeployContract.SendRequestAndWaitForReceiptAsync(ABI, byteCode, privateAccount, new HexBigInteger(gas.Value));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply create a new account with web3 when the blockchain is running the account's balance will be zero as it's an empty account. If you instead preseed account(s) with a balance upon creating the blockchain you can specify them a desired balance, at least in Ganache.

Here are some instructions for Ganache-CLI, probably something similar works for the non-CLI version: [Setting the initial balance of an account in ganache-cli](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38738/setting-the-initial-balance-of-an-account-in-ganache-cli)

The main idea is that once the blockchain is created the only way to create Ethers in the blockchain is by mining it - just like in the mainnet. But as you're using a private blockchain you can cheat a bit and add some Ethers into the blockchain upon creation and assign them to the desired accounts.

Comment: is it possible to add ether into account via web3.js library. Although i didnt find anything in the documentation.

Comment: No I don't think so. Web3 is for interacting with an existing blockchain and existing blockchain has very limited options for gaining Ether